# looped buttons with same name kivy python - how to clean all buttons or update all buttons with new variable

Tags: python, button, lambda, kivy

Good afternoon all,

My question is simple i guess, but not yet for me ;|

I created needed buttons with for loop in kivy.
While i'm switching between window using window manager and when i try go back to this one with that buttons, all new data and new buttons are generated, but i can't delete old ones.

My question is how can i update every button where name for each one is same because of this loop?

I'm able only last button delete using same lambda function.

if i create button with loop how can i get to each one ?
..by index? any chance ?
I'm using only python code without kivy language.

Please help
To generate buttons i used lambda function like this :

self.btn_flat.bind(on_release=lambda k=k: self.clicked(k,some variable))

i tried use     self.btn_flat.text = ''      in some places in code but nothing is working.

I hope so I explained my problem in right way.
Thank you for help!

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen
from kivymd.uix.button import MDTextButton


class TestApp(Screen):

def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    listt = ['abc', 'def', 'ghj']
    super(TestApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    odstep = 0.12
    xx = 0.10
    yy = 0.73
    for j, k in enumerate(listt):
        for m, poziomo in enumerate(k):
            if poziomo == ' ':
                continue
            else:
                self.btn_flat = MDTextButton(size_hint=(.05, .05), text=poziomo,
                                             pos_hint={'center_x': xx, 'center_y': yy})
                # TUTAJ bylo chyba najlepiej
                self.btn_flat.bind(on_release=lambda k=k: self.clicked(k))
                self.add_widget(self.btn_flat)
                xx = xx + odstep
            try:
                k[m + 1]
            except IndexError:
                yy = yy - 0.05
                xx = xx - (odstep * ((len(k) + 1) / 2))

    def clicked(self, dt):
        self.btn_flat.text = ''


class MyApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return TestApp()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: I tried give a solution but it not let me some reason.  Simple saying here that I don't want waste anyone time, self.clear_widgets() solve the problem which I found some tips on stackoverflow. Thank you !

Comment: End of ends I'm still looking answer for this question, any one can help please? Thank you